# amCharts tooltip is showing only on DateAxis but not ValueAxis

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, amcharts

I'm using amCharts and I'm making a XY Chart with multiple series, the tooltip shows ony when the X Axis type is `DateAxis` but not working when it's `ValueAxis`

```
var dateAxis = chart5.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
series.dataFields.dateX = "time";
```

amChart with tooltip:

[image: amChart with tooltip]

Now when I change these 2 lines to Value Axis it doesn't work

```
var dateAxis = chart5.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    series.dataFields.valueX = "time";
```

amChart without tooltip:

[image: amChart without tooltip]

Comment: Please post the rest of your code, preferably as a fiddle or runnable demo.

Answer (score 5):

I came across the same issue, and digging into the [library code](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/57587d05b19e14ab65ad8d350fc66393aef1e2c8/src/.internal/charts/series/XYSeries.ts#L1964), I realized ValueAxis doesn't implement [getSeriesDataItem](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/57587d05b19e14ab65ad8d350fc66393aef1e2c8/src/.internal/charts/axes/Axis.ts#L1900) method ([DateAxis](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/57587d05b19e14ab65ad8d350fc66393aef1e2c8/src/.internal/charts/axes/DateAxis.ts#L2283) and [CategoryAxis](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/blob/57587d05b19e14ab65ad8d350fc66393aef1e2c8/src/.internal/charts/axes/CategoryAxis.ts#L944) do). So, the solution for me was to implement that method. Based on the other axis implementations, the code I came out with was:

```
am4charts.ValueAxis.prototype.getSeriesDataItem = function (series, position) {
    var key = this.axisFieldName + this.axisLetter;
    var value = this.positionToValue(position);
    return series.dataItems.getIndex(series.dataItems.findClosestIndex(value, function(x) {
        return x[key];
    }, "any"));
}
```

After adding this prototype, tooltips works with no issues when using ValueAxis:

```js
/********** FIX: Add getSeriesDataItem method to ValueAxis ************/
am4charts.ValueAxis.prototype.getSeriesDataItem = function (series, position) {
    var key = this.axisFieldName + this.axisLetter;
    var value = this.positionToValue(position);
    return series.dataItems.getIndex(series.dataItems.findClosestIndex(value, function(x) {
        return x[key];
    }, "any"));
}
/**********************************************************************/
/* Create chart instance */
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

/* Add data */
chart.data = [{
  "xValue": 1000,
  "yValue": 1587
}, {
  "xValue": 1100,
  "yValue": 1567
}, {
  "xValue": 1250,
  "yValue": 1617
}, {
  "xValue": 1400,
  "yValue": 1630
}, {
  "xValue": 1700,
  "yValue": 1660
}, {
  "xValue": 1754,
  "yValue": 1683
}, {
  "xValue": 2255,
  "yValue": 1691
}, {
  "xValue": 3004,
  "yValue": 1298
}];

/* Create axes */
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

/* Create value axis */
var theYAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

/* Create series */
var series1 = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series1.dataFields.valueY = "yValue";
series1.dataFields.valueX = "xValue";
series1.name = "The X Axis";
series1.bullets.push(new am4charts.CircleBullet());
series1.tooltipText = "{valueY}";

/* Add legend */
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();

/* Create a cursor */
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="//www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a reply to the request to post an example of this (it's happening to me, too) from @xorspark :

XY chart, Y axis is ValueAxis, X axis is CategoryAxis.... and the tooltip works:
https://codepen.io/alavigne314/pen/JjozVWx

Same XY chart, but X axis is changed from CategoryAxis to ValueAxis... and the tooltip is gone:
https://codepen.io/alavigne314/pen/povYBdp

The changes between the two are only 3 lines:

```
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
theXAxis.dataFields.category = "xValue";
```

gets changed to

```
var theXAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
```

and

```
series1.dataFields.categoryX = "xValue";
```

gets changed to

```
series1.dataFields.valueX = "xValue";
```

Maybe we're both not reading something in the documentation correctly?  If so, I can't find out what it is.  Or perhaps... are tooltips broken or not supported in a both X-and-Y-ValueAxis chart?