# Amcharts tooltip broken when using DurationAxis

Tags: javascript, charts, tooltip, amcharts4

I have been trying to get tooltip working in amcharts4 when I use a DurationAxis(). It's likely a bug, as I get the tool tips sometimes appearing stuck in the top left corners.

Example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/jamiegau/fpye3bkv/25/

```
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "seconds": 1,
  "valueM": 12.1
}, {
  "seconds": 2,
  "valueM": 4.2
}, {
  "seconds": 4,
  "valueM": 7.3
}, {
  "seconds": 6,
  "valueM": 8.4
}, {
  "seconds": 9,
  "valueM": 4.5
}, {
  "seconds": 104,
  "valueM": 10.7
}];

var durationAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DurationAxis());
durationAxis.baseUnit = 'second';
durationAxis.title.text = 'Duration';
var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = 'valueM';
series.dataFields.valueX = 'seconds';
series.yAxis = valueAxis;
series.name = 'Momentary';
series.strokeWidth = 2;
series.minBulletDistance = 10;
series.tooltipText = 'M: {valueY}';
```

I have used this code before but with a DateAxis() without issue.  When I try DurationAxis(), it all goes to hell for tooltips.

In my real code, I have 4 different series.  But I have tried it with only 1 series.  pretty much tried everything..  Even going back to DateAxis, but that's not working for me as I need sub second accuracy, and when I go to DateAxes, it rounds it all to a second and looks terrible.

### Update

This also holds true on a valueAxis as well as DurationAxis.  I have looked into this more and it appears its not possible with amcharts to have POINT tooltips on these class of axis.

If I am wrong, please answer as such.

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting the same problem. Luckily, I found an answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64914695/3324314.

However, that answer was about `ValueAxis`, not the `DurationAxis`, but the concept is the same. Seems those classes don't define a required method, so you have to patch their prototypes. The following snippet has solved my issue:

```js
am4charts.DurationAxis.prototype.getSeriesDataItem = function (
      series,
      position
    ) {
      const key = this.axisFieldName + this.axisLetter
      const value = this.positionToValue(position)
      return series.dataItems.getIndex(
        series.dataItems.findClosestIndex(
          value,
          function (x) {
            return x[key]
          },
          'any'
        )
      )
    }
```